# Using SQL, when there are multiple columns with dates. how can I determine and return a row where the date is between the other rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I am building a table for a data warehouse that needs to have a row for each change that occurs. The issue is that there are sometimes changes that occur in the subgroups and I can't figure out how to show those changes.

For example, I have the [following table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/11d3d/1/0):

| RowNumber | Code | CorrectedProductYear | ProductYear | Product | CategoryYear | Category | PartYear | Parts | KeepRow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 2012 | 2012 | Sport Car | 1995 | Auto | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 2 | ABC | 2012 | 2012 | Sport Car | 1996 | Cars | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 3 | ABC | 2012 | 2012 | Sport Car | 1998 | Transport | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 4 | ABC | 2014 | 2014 | Sedan | 1995 | Auto | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 5 | ABC | 2014 | 2014 | Sedan | 1996 | Cars | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 6 | ABC | 2014 | 2014 | Sedan | 1998 | Transport | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 7 | ABC | 2018 | 2018 | Luxury Car | 1995 | Auto | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 8 | ABC | 2018 | 2018 | Luxury Car | 1996 | Cars | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 9 | ABC | 2018 | 2018 | Luxury Car | 1998 | Transport | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 10 | ABC | 2016 | 2018 | Sedan | 2016 | Vehicle | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 11 | ABC | 2018 | 2018 | Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 12 | ABC | 2018 | 2018 | Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 1980 | Wheels | N |
| 13 | ABC | 2019 | 2018 | Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 2019 | Fancy Wheels | Y |
| 14 | ABC | 2020 | 2020 | Super Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 2019 | Fancy Wheels | N |
| 15 | ABC | 2020 | 2020 | Super Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 2019 | Fancy Wheels | Y |

I marked the KeepRow with a 'Y' to show what the find result should look like. It should be this:

| RowNumber | Code | CorrectedProductYear | Product | CategoryYear | Category | PartYear | Parts | KeepRow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ABC | 2012 | Sport Car | 1998 | Transport | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 6 | ABC | 2014 | Sedan | 1998 | Transport | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 10 | ABC | 2016 | Sedan | 2016 | Vehicle | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 11 | ABC | 2018 | Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 1980 | Wheels | Y |
| 13 | ABC | 2019 | Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 2019 | Fancy Wheels | Y |
| 15 | ABC | 2020 | Super Luxury Car | 2017 | Motorcar | 2019 | Fancy Wheels | Y |

In this table the ProductYear is the "main" year. When the subgroupings (Category and Parts) have a change in their description/year, that needs to be captured in the ProductYear. This occurs in:

- Row 10 - where the Category changes to Vehicle in 2016, so it is between the ProductYear of 2014 Sedan and 2018 Luxury Car. Additionally, the Product needs to revert back to Sedan because Luxury Car had not yet been produced.
- Row 13 - Parts changes to Fancy Wheels in 2019 which is between the ProductYear of 2018 and 2020.

I know that I can do an Max Effective Date query to only pull the most recent CategoryYear and PartYear, but then I miss the changes that might occur between the ProductYear.

I've tried different variations of LAG and LEAD and well as LAST_VALUE and some of the other Window functions, but I'm at stuck and can't figure this one out.

I also think that this might not be able to be completed with just SQL. I do have the ability to do some SSIS if that is a better way to proceed.

Any help would be enormously appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I had to read this a few times and i still don't know what you want to do. Think about your problem this way... How do I get from my starting point to my ending point (even if that takes multiple iterations)? And then replicate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something like what you are looking for.  I had to split it into two queries as you are filtering once for CategoryYear and then again for PartYear.  This might help you get on the right path:

```
SELECT RowNumber,Code,CorrectedProductYear,ProductYear,Product,CategoryYear,Category,PartYear,Parts 
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product order by ProductYear) RN,
        LAG(ProductYear,1) OVER(order by ProductYear) LastProdYear,
        LEAD(ProductYear,1)  OVER(order by ProductYear) NextProdYear,
        LAG(Category,1) OVER(Order by Product,ProductYear) LastCategory
    FROM Products 
) T

WHERE  CategoryYear > LastProdYear and CategoryYear < NextProdYear
and KeepRow = 'Y' and Category <> LastCategory and RN > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT RowNumber,Code,CorrectedProductYear,ProductYear,Product,CategoryYear,Category,PartYear,Parts 
FROM
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Product order by ProductYear) RN,
        LAG(ProductYear,1) OVER(order by ProductYear) LastProdYear,
        LEAD(ProductYear,1)  OVER(order by ProductYear) NextProdYear,
        LAG(Parts,1) OVER(Order by Product,ProductYear) LastParts
    FROM Products 
) T
WHERE  PartYear > LastProdYear and PartYear < NextProdYear
and KeepRow = 'Y' and Parts <> LastParts and RN > 1
```

Comment: Thank you! Splitting it up makes so much more sense but I just wasn't able to see that.